# Shapefile with point or polygon

Tags: shapefile, polygon, fields-attributes

I'm just beginning with SIG and QGIS.
I've been given two shapefiles with cities.
One shapefile appears like point shapefile in QGIS, the other like polygon shapefile.
The problem is that the polygons's one is not complete.
When I open the attribute table, the two are basically the same, with x, y and surface.
So I assume I could take the point shapefile and make it polygon but I am not sure and I don't know how to do this.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. What's "SIG"? If you mean "GIS" please edit the question.

Comment: Can you elaborate further on how the polygon shapefile is not complete?

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to transfert attributes based on spatial relationship.
You can use a spatial Join.
QGIS have a *Join Attributes by Location* tool.

Here an example: http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/performing_spatial_joins.html